# Need some help, callback an array from textarea in googlescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, callback, textarea

I need some fresh eyes on what I'm trying to do. I'm working on making our inventory spreadsheet more accurate and email a person when we get low on something. I got most of the code done, there's one part that I'm having issues with and it's where we add a number to certain parts of the spreadsheet. To be more exact, I'm trying to have a menu with multiple text areas for each part, and each text area will relate to the number that we just bought of that part.

My current code for this section has an array that will create and add the textarea to the panel and the part that is labeled in the spreadsheet. A button that will add the text area to the spreadsheet.

My issue that I'm having is correctly setting up the .addCallbackElement() with an array and get whats in the text area to the spreadsheet.

Can anyone see where I am making the mistake, or possible recommendation at something better that I could do?

Thanks for any help that is given

```
  function addBit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet0 = ss.getSheetByName('Inventory');
  var lastrow0 = sheet0.getLastRow();
  //var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  //data for each column that we need
  var datarange0 = sheet0.getRange('D2:D'+lastrow0);
  var datarange1 = sheet0.getRange('E2:E'+lastrow0);
  var datarange2 = sheet0.getRange('F2:F'+lastrow0);
  var datarange3 = sheet0.getRange('K2:K'+lastrow0);
  var datarange4 = sheet0.getRange('I2:I'+lastrow0);
  var data0 = datarange0.getValues();// Column D
  var data1 = datarange1.getValues();// Column E
  var data2 = datarange2.getValues();// Column F
  var data3 = datarange3.getValues();// Column K
  var data4 = datarange4.getValues();// Column I
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.setHeight(500).setWidth(500);
  var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(500,500);
  var vpanel0 = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var vpanel1 = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var hpanel0 = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  var apanel = app.createAbsolutePanel();
  var text = new Array(lastrow0-1);
  //creating labels and text areas for each part for the first column in the menu
  for (var i = 0; i <= Math.round((lastrow0 - 2)/2); i++) {
    var hpanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
    var label = app.createLabel(data0[i]+ ' ' + data1[i] + 'mm ('+ Math.round(data2[i]) + 'mil)');
    text[i] = app.createTextArea().setName('text'+i).setSize(50,20).setValue(0);//.setId('text'+i);
    hpanel.add(text[i]);
    hpanel.add(label);
    vpanel0.add(hpanel);
  }
  //creating labels and text areas for each part for the second column in the menu
  for (var i = Math.round((lastrow0 - 2)/2) + 1; i <= lastrow0 - 2; i++) {
    var hpanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
    var label = app.createLabel(data0[i]+ ' ' + data1[i] + 'mm ('+ Math.round(data2[i]) + 'mil)');
    text[i] = app.createTextArea().setName('text'+i).setSize(50,20).setValue(0);//.setId('text'+i);
    hpanel.add(text[i]);
    hpanel.add(label);
    vpanel1.add(hpanel);
  }
  //Creating handlers for the text areas
  var thandler = app.createServerHandler('addition');
  for (var j = 0; j <= lastrow0 - 2; j++) {
    thandler.addCallbackElement(text[j]).setId('text'+i);
  }
  //when button is hit, the function 'addition' will run
  var addButton = app.createButton("Add", thandler);
  hpanel0.add(vpanel0);
  hpanel0.add(vpanel1);
  apanel.add(hpanel0);
  apanel.add(addButton);
  scroll.add(apanel);
  app.add(scroll);

  return app;
}
function addition(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet0 = ss.getSheetByName('Inventory');
  var lastrow0 = sheet0.getLastRow();
  //data for each column
  var datarange3 = sheet0.getRange('K2:K'+lastrow0);
  var datarange4 = sheet0.getRange('I2:I'+lastrow0);
  var data3 = datarange3.getValues();// Column K
  var data4 = datarange4.getValues();// Column I
  var text0 = new Array(lastrow0-1);
  //text0[] will have what was in each text area
  for (var i = 0; i <= lastrow0 - 2; i++) {
    text0[i] = e.parameter.('text' + 1);
  }
  //for loop will add what was in the text area to columns 'Qty Acq' and 'Current Stock'
  for (var j = 0; j <= lastrow0-2; j++) {
    var k = j+2;
    var v = data3[j] + text0[j];
    var x = data4[j] + text0[j]
    sheet0.getRange('M' + k).setValue(v);
    sheet0.getRange('N' + k).setValue(x);
  }
  app.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the highest level panel (scrollpanel I guess) as a single callbackElement, it will automatically include all the child widgets.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, it does work on getting callback to work but my problem now is retrieving the data from the text area. I can do text0 = e.parameter.text0; and it will work. What I need to get e.parameter.text0 to e.parameter.text(lastrow). e.parameter.text + i; doesn't work either. I've tried join() and split() but then I get "TextArea" as the value.

Comment: the syntax is e.parameter['text' + i]

Comment: Thank you Serge insas, that did it. All the other issues that I'm currently having now, I should be able to handle.